# Run powershell command as a background

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I need to trigger TFS build run command as a background process. How can i do it in Powershell? I have tried to use Start-Job command but it does not work. Need your help.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TFSBuild.exe start  /collection:"https://test.tfs.siemens.net/test" /builddefinition:"Test\Test.build"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `start-process` command to launch the script. This will make sure that the launched job keeps running when the task is finished. But the job will be closed when the build is finished.

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList '-file xxxx.ps1'
```